# Preventing the back button of the phone to go to certain page (PhoneGap 3.2)

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I have a PhoneGap app where the first page is a login form. Once the user logs in, he will navigate back and forth between the pages.

If the user presses the back button on the phone, he will go one step back, and eventually go back to the login screen.

Is there a way to know which page the back-operation will take the user to? So that I could prevent the back-behaviour only in cases where the login screen will be shown.

So the phone's back button should still be functional, but if the back button will lead to the login screen, the back-behaviour should be prevented.

Comment: Rfer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071652/how-to-prevent-going-back-to-previous-page

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way to accomplish it is by adding listener to back button. So code should look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
    {
        if (/*check to decide what to do*/)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

For check you can use $.mobile.activePage (if you use JQuery Mobile), browser history, your hand-made history or something else.

Comment: Great, but is there a way to know which page the backHistory() action will lead to? So that I can build the correct conditional statement.

Comment: @Publicus after reading about browser history in the internet i came to conclusion that in this situation it may be easier to implement your own simple history rather than using some not-standard libraries... If you can add event listener for page changing (or something else like "pageshow" event in JQuery Mobile), than you can simply add/remove entries from your history array and look in this array during backbutton event.